# Close connection to signalR on server

Tags: signalr-hub

I would like to disconnect the hub on the server. I have alternative code to use when the signalR connection is lost. I dont want the connection going up again.

This is just for test purpose, anyone got a solution?

Comment: You need to send a signal to the client to disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Write a disconnect event on your client that the server can call through SignalR. Like this:

```
myHub.client.serverOrderedDisconnect = function (value) { $.connection.hub.stop(); };
```

Then, on the server, like this:

```
Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).serverOrderedDisconnect();
```

Happy to Help you